# MyBase (base) Object Property not showing actual value in the debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, virtual

So I get a paniced IM from a coworker saying this if statement is skipping when

```
If true Then
    DoSomething
End IF
```

The actual code being

```
If MyBase.IsDirty Then
    DoSomething
End IF
```

C# Version

```
if(base.IsDirty)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

My first question to them was well the `If` statement isn't magically broken so are you sure `MyBase.IsDirty` is actually true? They responded 'Yes OF COURSE!'. Upon asking them how they determined this they said they were putting a breakpoint at the line and hovering over `MyBase.IsDirty` to see what the value was and that they had also done `?MyBase.IsDirty` in the immediate window. My initial thought and what I am thinking to still be correct is due to the way that base classes function that it wasn't actually showing the value at in those cases (at least the correct one) so I suggested doing

`Dim dirty As Boolean = MyBase.IsDirty`

Then running the code again, which showed as I guessed that dirty was actually `false`.

Now why is this the case? As far as I can tell it has something to do with the way that MyBase is implemented but I want specifics so I can have a 100% answer to this.

**Edit**

Right so `MyBase.IsDirty` is a Boolean

The Get is done as Follows:

```
<Browsable(False)> _
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property IsDirty() As Boolean Implements IEditableBusinessObject.IsDirty
      Get
        Return IsSelfDirty OrElse (_fieldManager IsNot Nothing AndAlso FieldManager.IsDirty())
      End Get
    End Property
```

Where

```
<Browsable(False)> _
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property IsSelfDirty() As Boolean Implements IEditableBusinessObject.IsSelfDirty
      Get
        Return _isDirty
      End Get
    End Property
```

And

`_isDirty` is Initialized as true

(Field Manager is a non issue for this case).

I should note that this is all taken from CSLA 3.5.3.0

**Another Edit**

I'm calling MyBase.IsDirty because that is the way that `Rocky Lhotka` shows it being done in his books on CSLA.

Comment: What is the type of `IsDirty`?

Comment: If `MyBase` is a property, it could be useful to see how the `Get` is done.

Comment: @Justin: It seems to be a `Boolean`, judging by the code that he posted. Agree with @Shimrod; please post your `IsDirty` property. Incidentally, why are you calling `MyBase.IsDirty` instead of just `IsDirty`? Are you overriding it in the current class and you want to bypass that logic?

Comment: @Adam Robinson see the edits, @Shimrod in the edit, @Justin yes....

Comment: @CodeInChaos, care to elaborate in an answer this is exactly the type of thing I am wanting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger can't evaluate expressions using the `base` (or `MyBase` in VB) keyword correctly because the debugging API doesn't support non virtual calls. It returns the value a virtual call to the getter returns instead of the one the getter in the base class returns. So the effect you're observing is a debugger problem.

I guess you overrode the property in the derived class and return `false` there, and that's what the debugger shows. The compiled code itself will handle the `base.` call correctly.

The MSDN blog entry ["Debugger won't properly evaluate C#s base keyword"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/06/29/funceval-does-virtual-dispatch.aspx) describes this problem in detail

Comment: this is what I thought, but I couldn't find anything specific/official.

Comment: @msarchet found the msdn blog